# Error when calculating variable importance with categorical variables using the caret package (varImp)

Tags: r, r-caret, feature-selection

I've been trying to compute the variable importance for a model with mixed scale features using the `varImp` function in the `caret` package. I've tried a number of approaches, including renaming and coding my levels numerically. In each case, I am getting the following error:

```
Error in auc3_(actual, predicted, ranks) : 
  Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double].
```

The following dummy example should illustrate my point (edited to reflect @StupidWolf's correction):

```
library(caret)

#create small dummy dataset
set.seed(124)
dummy_data = data.frame(Label = factor(sample(c("a","b"),40, replace = TRUE)))
dummy_data$pred1 = ifelse(dummy_data$Label=="a",rnorm(40,-.5,2),rnorm(40,.5,2))
dummy_data$pred2 = factor(ifelse(dummy_data$Label=="a",rbinom(40,1,0.3),rbinom(40,1,0.7)))


# check varImp
control.lvq <- caret::trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3)
model.lvq <- caret::train(Label~., data=dummy_data, 
                          method="lvq", preProcess="scale", trControl=control.lvq)
varImp.lvq <- caret::varImp(model.lvq, scale=FALSE)
```

The issue persists when using different models (like randomForest and SVM).

If anyone knows a solution or can tell me what is going wrong, I would highly appreciate that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you call varImp on lvq , it defaults to `filterVarImp()` because there is no specific variable importance for this model. Now if you check the [help page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-86/topics/filterVarImp):

> For two class problems, a series of cutoffs is applied to the
> predictor data to predict the class. The sensitivity and specificity
> are computed for each cutoff and the ROC curve is computed.

Now if you read the [source code of varImp.train()](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/pkg/caret/R/varImp.train.R)  that feeds the data into `filterVarImp()`, it is the original dataframe and not whatever comes out of the preprocess.

This means in the original data, if you have a variable that is a factor, it cannot cut the variable, it will throw and error like this:

```
filterVarImp(data.frame(dummy_data$pred2),dummy_data$Label)
Error in auc3_(actual, predicted, ranks) : 
  Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double].
```

So using my example and like you have pointed out, you need to onehot encode it:

```
set.seed(111)
dummy_data = data.frame(Label = rep(c("a","b"),each=20))
dummy_data$pred1 = rnorm(40,rep(c(-0.5,0.5),each=20),2)
dummy_data$pred2 = rbinom(40,1,rep(c(0.3,0.7),each=20))
dummy_data$pred2 = factor(dummy_data$pred2)

control.lvq <- caret::trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3)

ohe_data = data.frame(
            Label = dummy_data$Label,
            model.matrix(Label ~ 0+.,data=dummy_data))

model.lvq <- caret::train(Label~., data=ohe_data, 
                          method="lvq", preProcess="scale",
                       trControl=control.lvq)

caret::varImp(model.lvq, scale=FALSE)  

ROC curve variable importance

       Importance
pred1      0.6575
pred20     0.6000
pred21     0.6000
```

If you use a model that doesn't have a specific variable importance method, then one option is that you can already calculate the variable importance first, and run the model after that.

Comment: Thanks, @StupidWolf, for pointing out the problem with the predictors. I ran your example. However, I am still getting an error message:
```
Error in y - mean(y, rm.na = TRUE) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(y, rm.na = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```
Since it appears to work for you, could it be a version problem? I am running on R version 4.0.3 and caret is on version 6.0-86.
After setting the Label and pred2 to factors, I get the same error as described in my original post.

Comment: Nothing to do with R versions.. check what you are doing next time @hanibal

Comment: Ok. I was hoping caret was able to handle categorical variables internally and compute a single variable importance for categorical features. Thanks for clarifying that this does not seem to be the case. I elaborated that in the answer I posted -- maybe it wasn't too clear since it got pushed down ;-). Thanks for the link.

Comment: I wasn't aware that preProcess was also applied to categorical data. Actually, the issue appears to persist for me after removing the preProcess argument in caret::train (at least without encoding the categorical data first).

Comment: Yup you are right.. Ok I have to read the code in detail. The AUC function used by caret::varImp cannot handle the factor

Comment: Commenting to say I am also facing this same problem. While reading "Applied Predictive Modeling" (by Max Kuhn who also wrote filterVarImp), I decided to try out filterVarImp to get some quick variable importance scores during an EDA. I have been getting the same error as above ("Error in auc3_(actual, predicted, ranks) :....etc"). To be clear, is the only solution for this to one-hot encode all categorical features?

Comment: right now yes, if you want to go with caret that is

Answer (score 1):

Note that this problem can be circumvented by replacing ordinal features (with d levels) by its (d-1)-dimensional indicator encoding:

```
model.matrix(~dummy_data$pred2-1)[,1:(length(levels(dummy_data$pred2)-1)]
```

However, why does varImp not handle this automatically? Further, this has the drawback that it yields an importance score for each of the d-1 indicators, not one unified importance score for the original feature.